# How can I use the NumPy C-API in both C++ header and source file?

Tags: c++, templates, numpy, header-files

I am making Python code available to a C++ library using Boost::Python. I have a template function that converts C++ types to Python types:

```
template <typename T> bp::object convert(T v);
```

that is specialized for various primitive types as well as some templated classes. One such class is an N-dimensional Array, for which I have a function to convert to a NumPy Array. I'd like to use this function in a corresponding `convert` specialization, e.g.:

```
template <typename Y> bp::object convert(NDArray<Y> v);
```

My primary issue is that this conversion function then needs to live in a header since it's templated, but it uses NumPy's `PyArray_` functions, which require `import_array()` to be called prior to usage. `import_array()` is currently called in the constructor for a singleton object whose purpose is to provide access to Python functions. It appears this won't work because, by default, `#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>` only makes the `PyArray_` functions available to the current compilation unit. I've tried defining a `PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL` and defining `NO_IMPORT_ARRAY` for the header, but this doesn't prevent `PyArray_` functions from segfaulting.

Here's a simplified representation of my code, which segfaults upon using a `PyArray_` function in the "conversions.h" header:

"conversions.h":

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <numpy/numpyconfig.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

namespace bp = boost::python;

template <typename T> bp::object convert(T v);
template <> bp::object convert<int>(int v) { return bp::long_(v); }
...
template <typename Y> bp::object convert(NDArray<Y> v)
{
... use PyArray_ functions to create and return a NumPy array
... segfaults here!
}
```

"Bridge.h":

```
#include "conversions.h"

class Bridge {
public:
    static Bridge* instance();

    // c++11 variadic template (parameter pack)
    template <typename... Args> void exec(Args... args)
    {
        ...
        fn(convert(args)...); // fn is a Python function
        ...
    }
    void foo();

private:
    Bridge();
    Bridge(const Bridge&);
    void operator=(const Bridge&);
    static Bridge* instance_;
}
```

"Bridge.cpp":

```
#include "Bridge.h"
#include <numpy/numpyconfig.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

Bridge* Bridge::instance_ = nullptr;
Bridge* Bridge::instance() {
    if (!instance_) { instance_ = new Bridge(); }
    return instance_;
}
Bridge::Bridge() {
    Py_Initialize();
    _import_array();
    ...
}
void Bridge::foo() {
    ... // other stuff using PyArray functions
}
```

"main.cpp":

```
#include "Bridge.h"

int main(void)
{
    NDArray my_array(...);
    Bridge::instance()->exec(42, "hello", my_array); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since learned that one problem is that the calls to the PyArray functions should happen in the same compilation unit as the call to `import_array` (the NumPy initialization function).

One way to solve this problem is to "wrap" the `PyArray_*` functions internally and use them rather than the NumPy API directly.

There may be another solution found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html#required-subroutine).

My solution:

Create a "numpy_wrappers.h" file:

```
...
#include "numpy/ndarraytypes.h"

int NumPyArray_NDIM(PyObject* obj);
npy_intp NumPyArray_DIM(PyObject* obj, int i);
void *NumPyArray_DATA(PyObject* obj);
...
```

Then implement these by "wrapping" the original functions in **the same source file as your call to** `import_array` (the NumPy initialization function):

```
...
Bridge::Bridge() {
    Py_Initialize();
    _import_array();
    ...
}
...
/// Wraps PyArray_NDIM
int NumPyArray_NDIM(PyObject* obj)
{
    return PyArray_NDIM((PyArrayObject*)obj);
}

/// Wraps PyArray_DIM
npy_intp NumPyArray_DIM(PyObject* obj, int i)
{
    return PyArray_DIM((PyArrayObject*)obj, i);
}

/// Wraps PyArray_DATA
void* NumPyArray_DATA(PyObject* obj)
{
    return PyArray_DATA((PyArrayObject*)obj);
}
...
```

Then they can be used in template headers, like so:

```
...
template <typename Y> bp::object convert(NDArray<Y> v)
{
... use NumPyArray_ functions to create and return a NumPy array
... No more segfaults!
}
...
```

You can see an in-depth implementation of this [here](https://github.com/gadgetron/gadgetron/tree/master/toolboxes/python), a toolbox for seamlessly converting between some C++ STL types and Python standard types.