# Implicit declaration of function 'PyArray_DATA'

Tags: python, c, numpy, header-files, swig

I'm trying to write a library in C which take in inputs a list of numpy array following the answer of this [Calling C from Python: passing list of numpy pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384129/calling-c-from-python-passing-list-of-numpy-pointers)
post. In my header file I include:

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
```

but when I call:

```
PyArray_DATA(PyList_GetItem(list,i))
```

where `i` is an index that runs over the list's elements, I get a compilation error:

```
Implicit declaration of function 'PyArray_DATA' is invalid in C99
```

How can I fix it?

My xcode version is 10.1. I work with a script in Python 3.5 where my list of numpy array is created and use swig to interface with my C library.

Comment: I think you need to include `<numpy/arrayobject.h>` for this. I'm not sure how the include statement would look for a framework on macOS, though.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/28483819/694576 if not a dupe to it.

Comment: @Blaze and indeed I get a file not found error...

Comment: @alk I'm sorry but I don't know c++ so I have a some difficulties in understanding your link and the solution... and moreover, as I wrote, I'm not able to include numpy header files which seems to be needed in that answer too

Comment: Try browsing the `Python` framework on macOS and see if `arrayobject.h` is in there somewhere. The `numpy` libraries might already be included in the framework by default.

Comment: @Blaze I find different arrayobject.h... this is because with anaconda I use different environments ... but how do I tell xcode to include it?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I don't have access to  macOS installation right now. Perhaps you can install the library with homebrew or download the binary somewhere, although I didn't have any luck finding it.